# Dirty git commits

Tags: git, github

I use CRLF = true, but commits are anyway dirty.
[image]

[image]

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding .gitattribute file to the root directory of project with value:

```
* text = auto
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By setting `autocrlf` to `true`, you are telling Git to convert LF line endings into CRLF upon checkout.  That is the message that you are receiving and the expected behavior.

If you don't want to change LF to CRLF, then set `autocrlf` to `false`.

Otherwise, you'd need to find out which host is pushing content files with LF instead of CRLF if you don't want the remote files to have LF (and instead have CRLF).

It sounds like there may be a Linux or Mac machine that has `autocrlf` set to `input`, which would change CRLFs to LFs when they are committing.  Perhaps this is the undesired effect?

With `autocrlf` you really need to think through how you want line feeds to be represented in the repository, as well as which machines and OSes are contributing when determining the correct options to set on the hosts.

Those are the only two courses of action I can see possible in this situation.